# Drupal 7 Views Exposed Combine contains any word filter case sensitivity

Tags: views

There is a problem with case sensitivity, using the combined filter in Views.
I find a solution for the operator "contains" at drupal.org using LOWER

But I use the **operator "contains any word."** **Can anyone help correct change code from views/handlers/views_handler_filter_combine.inc**

(need to LOWER search query and the fields in which there is a search)

```
function op_word($field) {
$where = $this->operator == 'word' ? db_or() : db_and();

// Don't filter on empty strings.
if (empty($this->value)) {
  return;
}

preg_match_all('/ (-?)("[^"]+"|[^" ]+)/i', ' ' . $this->value, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
  $phrase = FALSE;
  // Strip off phrase quotes.
  if ($match[2]{0} == '"') {
    $match[2] = substr($match[2], 1, -1);
    $phrase = TRUE;
  }
  $words = trim($match[2], ',?!();:-');
  $words = $phrase ? array($words) : preg_split('/ /', $words, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  $placeholder = $this->placeholder();
  foreach ($words as $word) {
    $where->where($field . " LIKE $placeholder", array($placeholder => '%' . db_like(trim($word, " ,!?")) . '%'));

}

}

if (!$where) {
  return;
}

// Previously this was a call_user_func_array() but that's unnecessary
// as views will unpack an array that is a single arg.
$this->query->add_where($this->options['group'], $where);
  }
```

I tried to do this myself, but my PHP knowledges is not good.
Thanks!